# Setting both border-left and border-right for a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Forgive me if my question is very basic. I have a div as follows:

```
<div id="container">...</div>
```

Now, I'm trying to set both `border-left` and `border-right` attributes for the `div` in a script:

```
<script>
   var div = document.getElementById("container");
   div.style.borderLeft = "1px solid white";
   div.style.borderRight = "1px solid white";
</script>
```

The problem is that the attribute I set second always overrides the first one, i.e here only `borderRight` is set for the `div`. If I put `style.borderRight` followed by `style.borderLeft`, then it sets only `border-left` attribute. Why is this happening? It works fine if I set it directly in the css.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce. http://jsfiddle.net/s29pzjtn/ Maybe there is something else on the page?

Comment: As dsfq said, your code should work. Can you post more code, i.e. other script or styling you have on that page?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue either http://jsfiddle.net/mon9otmx/

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ktd43thd/.

Comment: Guys, I'm extremely sorry. I had mis-spelt the value as "1px soild white" @_@. It's working now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery

```
$("#container").attr("style"," border-left: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white")
```

this will add attribute style to the div with id "container" and with both borders as a value.